# Why is edoc unable to discover callbacks?

Tags: erlang, code-documentation

For some time we are able to declare behaviour callback using -callback attribute instead of behaviour_info/1 (which in my opinion is more convenient). But, the edoc application seems to be unable to discover such attribute. Still, release notes suggested, that this issue was already fixed in version 0.7.10 (http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/edoc/notes.html). Did anyone encounter similar problem and was able to overcome it?

Comment: edoc 0.7.10 was released with Erlang/OTP R15B02.  What's your Erlang/OTP version?

Comment: I just updated to R16B01, so it should not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the open issue [3211](https://github.com/erlang/otp/issues/3211) is talking about a similar issue.

There is a comment mentioning that commit [715bb80](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/715bb8044600ec16ad6ba97de9d033f6a5c06bfe) enables edocs to identify callbacks, but I am also seeing this functionality in the [brod](https://github.com/kafka4beam/brod/blob/master/src/brod_group_subscriber.erl#L94-L99) project -- [hexdocs](https://hexdocs.pm/brod/brod_group_subscriber.html).